# How to design a wpf Application with more than 500 pages

Tags: wpf, architecture, navigation

I have an application (a medical therapy kind of) in which there are more than 500 pages to navigate through and some processing is done in some of the pages. How should i design such an application.

Currently I have a main window on which there is a frame and inside the frame I am embedding these pages, but for each page I have to create that much number of xaml pages ( I feel its bulky creating such huge number of xaml pages).

Can anyone suggest a better design or approach.

Comment: What is the format of the data?  What processing is done in some of the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a framework designed specifically for this type of large composite applications.

The framework is PRISM 4, see: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

> Prism provides guidance designed to help you more easily design and
>   build rich, flexible, and easy-to-maintain Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) desktop applications, Silverlight Rich Internet
>   Applications (RIAs), and Windows Phone 7 applications. Using design
>   patterns that embody important architectural design principles, such
>   as separation of concerns and loose coupling, Prism helps you to
>   design and build applications using loosely coupled components that
>   can evolve independently but that can be easily and seamlessly
>   integrated into the overall application. These types of applications
>   are known as composite applications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the application is mainly a document viewer. If that is true then the document could be stored in some sort of markup with some sort of special trigger for active content that includes processing.

When displaying a page the application would process the markup and convert it to WPF display format and when active processing requirement is detected the program could insert specialized user controls or use some other system for interacting with the page.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @Doug, it appears you are looking for a document viewer. In that case, I think what you really want is just a "virtualized document", where only the page currently presented instantiated (somewhat similar to Virtualized Stack Panel, which is what ListBox is using).

In recent year I became a great fan of the MVVM design pattern. In your case, I think in your View Model you should have a currentPage property (a sub view model), and a view (i.e. XAML) that knows how to render this page using Binding - probably a Data Template.

As you move between pages, you'll just change the currentPage property in your ViewModel. Everything should update automatically (once INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented correctly). If rendering the View is too slow, consider adding a cache mechanism.